# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM' when extracting year from datetime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to extract 'YEAR' from a specific date time using a SQL query and ASP.NET C# but I get

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

I tried to figure out for so many days but I could not find the answer. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my SQL query?

```
String theDate="";
String sQuery = "SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM StartDateTime) AS MyDates FROM Date WHERE DateID='1'";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, conn);

conn.Open();

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.Read())
{
    theDate=dr["MyDates"].ToString();
}

conn.Close();
dr.Close();
```

Comment: Is the SQL Server?

Comment: `Date` is a keyword, why are you using it as table name?

Comment: Please tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Date should be enclosed with square brackets, i.e. "[Date]" to identify a table name instead of a SQL keyword. I recommend to avoid using default SQL keywords as table name.

Comment: This is MySQL syntax, it won't work on SQL Server. SQL Server does not have the `EXTRACT` function/operator. Use `DATEPART(yy, StartDateTime)` instead. See [MSDN Documentation for DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try this SQL Query

```
select DATEPART(yy, date) AS MyDates FROM Date WHERE DateID='1'";
```

Use DatePart Function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use datepart

```
select DATEPART(year, startdatetime) AS MyDates 
from Date 
where DateID = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is [MySQL syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_extract.asp):

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM StartDateTime)
```

It won't work on SQL Server. Instead, to extract the year of a DateTime value in SQL Server you must use [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

> DATEPART ( datepart , date )

`datepart` can be several values but according to the documentation, to extract the year you can use `yy` or `yyyy`, and observations indicate that `year` also work.

So your SQL should be this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, StartDateTime) AS MyDates FROM Date WHERE DateID='1'
```